# C# send key to bloomberg

Tags: c#, vba, sendkeys, bloomberg, dde

My boss asked me to transform the following VBA code in to C# (I am new to C#)

```
Sub BBG()

Dim stockname As String 
Dim test As String
stockname = ActiveCell
test = InStr(1, stockname, "Equity")
stockname = Left(stockname, InStr(1, stockname, "Equity") - 2) & " <EQUITY>"

Blp = DDEInitiate("Winblp", "bbk")
Call DDEExecute(Blp, "<Blp-1>" & stockname & " GPC<GO>")
Call DDETerminate(ch)

End Sub
```

So, I am trying in this way:

1. Activate the bloomberg windows
2. Send the key into bloomberg, eg: send "IBM US EQUITY MACD" and hit "Enter"

For example:

```
namespace sendkey
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        [DllImportAttribute("User32.dll")]
        private static extern int FindWindow(String ClassName, String WindowName);

        [DllImportAttribute("User32.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr SetForegroundWindow(int hWnd);

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            int hWnd = FindWindow(null, "Name of Bloomberg windows");
            if (hWnd > 0) 
            {
                SetForegroundWindow(hWnd); //Activate it
                SendKeys.SendWait("IBM US EQUITY MACD");
                SendKeys.SendWait("{enter}");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Window Not Found!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But now, the problem is that:

1. I don't know the name of the bloomberg windows as my PC is not installed with bloomberg.
2. From the VBA code, what does the code in <> mean? For example, when I want to send a "Enter" to Bloomberg, which one should I type {Enter} OR  < GO >  in my code ??

Thank you so much, I am really confused :(

Comment: Well the original VBA code is _Dynamic Data Exchange (DDE)_ **not** _sending keystrokes_.  Does the app still support DDE?  Either your question is about using DDE under .NET or how to send keystrokes.

Answer (score 0):

C#/.NET applications integrates with Bloomberg Terminal using TerminalConnect Api.

For example, the following code loads 'IBM US Equity' into Panel #1, then runs MACD function:

```
BlpTerminal.RunFunction("MACD", "1", new List<string>() {"IBM US Equity"});
```

For more information on TerminalConnect SDK, please contact *terminalapi@bloomberg.net*.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this which allows to log in automatically on bloomberg

```
            var p = new Process();
            p.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\BLP\wintrv\WINTRV.EXE";
            p.StartInfo.EnvironmentVariables["sessioname"] = "Console";
            p.StartInfo.EnvironmentVariables["SESSIONNAME"] = "Console";
            p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            p.Start();
            Thread.Sleep(45000);


        IntPtr handle = FindWindow(null, "1-BLOOMBERG");
        if (!handle.Equals(IntPtr.Zero))
        {
            if (SetForegroundWindow(handle))
            {
                Thread.Sleep(5000);
                SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}");
                Thread.Sleep(3000);
                SendKeys.SendWait("USER");
                Thread.Sleep(5000);
                SendKeys.SendWait("{TAB}");
                Thread.Sleep(3000);
                SendKeys.SendWait("PASSWORD");
                SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}");
            }
        }
```